# Dynamic div creation in Streamlit

Tags: python, html, django, dynamic, streamlit

How do I create dynamic divs with StreamLit framework in Python? Basically I want to create as many divs as there are number of posts in my python list. I want something similar to what is happening in the below HTML code

```
<div class="mt-3 p-3 bg-white rounded box-shadow  border border-gray">
    <h6 class="border-bottom border-gray pb-2 mb-0">Verwandte Posts</h6>
    <div class="media text-muted pt-3">
        {% load app_tags %}
        {% for post in posts.related_posts %}
        <a href="{% url 'post_detail' post.slug  %}">{{ post.title }}</a>
      </p>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using [`st.container()`](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/layout/st.container) since Streamlit [0.86.0](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/changelog#version-0860):

```py
import streamlit as st

def create_random_string():
    import random
    import string
    return "".join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in range(10))

class Post:
    def __init__(self):
        self.title = create_random_string()
        self.text = create_random_string()

posts = [Post() for _ in range(10)]

for post in posts:
    with st.container():
        st.title(post.title)
        st.markdown(f"Text {post.text}")
```

It gives:

[image: Posts title and text]